# How to detect the dismissal of a bootstrap modal dialog in javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, dismiss

I am trying to work with the bootstrap modal dialog. The events I am using are `hidden` and `show`. I have no problem using the `show` event. I don't understand how to use the `hidden` event on the other hand. I am displaying a form in the modal dialog and on the `submit` event of the form, I am hiding the modal dialog with `$('.modal').modal('hide')`. This hide event is also fired when the modal is dismissed either by using the close icon, by clicking an abort button which has this markup `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Abort</button>`, by pressing the escape key or by clicking somewhere on the `.modal-backdrop`. How can I distinguish a successful form submission from a dismissal of the dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this issue in a slightly hacky way: When the form is submitted, i change the value of a custom data attribute of an element that is not part of the form being submitted. When the `hidden` event fires, I compare the values of my custom data attribute with the current value of the input element in the form that was displayed in the modal. If the two values differ, the modal has been dismissed, otherwise it was submitted.

```
$( '#modalWithForm' ).on( 'submit', 'form', function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
        url: $( this ).attr( 'action' ),
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            param: parseInt( $( '#input' ).val(), 10),
        }
    } ).done( function ( ) {
        $( 'label[data-custom]' ).data( 'custom', $( '#input' ).val() );
        $( '#modalWithForm' ).modal( 'hide' );
    } );
} );

$( '#modalWithForm' ).on( 'hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    var modalDismissed = parseInt( $( '#input' ).val(), 10 ) !== parseInt( $( 'label[data-custom]' ).data( 'custom' ) );
    $.ajax( {
        url: '/Update',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: "text",
        data: {
            param: parseInt( modalDismissed ? $( 'label[data-custom]' ).data( 'custom' ) : $( '#input' ).val(), 10 )
        }
    } ).done( function ( updatedForm ) {
        $('form').empty().html(updatedForm);
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Bootstrap 3:

```
$('#yourModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  // code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I am using the 'hide' event already. The problem is the 'hide' and the 'hidden' event get fired no matter if the form has been successfully submitted or the dialog was dismissed. I need to be able to distinguish the two.

Comment: You can listen for the button event, and inside this event dismiss the modal. Otherwise, the modal was dismissed by the X button.